# c# linq rather complex sorting

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of objects I need to massage into a rather complex sort order.

I am a complete newbie to linq and c#/.net (but not to programming in other languages), so I would love some hints in what direction I need to go.

My list (simplified) looks like this:

```
List[
    {nr:  1, originatesFrom: null, lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,3)},
    {nr:  2, originatesFrom: null, lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,3)},
    {nr:  3, originatesFrom: null, lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,3)},
    {nr:  4, originatesFrom: 1,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,1)},
    {nr:  5, originatesFrom: 2,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,1)},
    {nr:  6, originatesFrom: 1,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,7)},
    {nr:  7, originatesFrom: 1,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,4)},
    {nr:  8, originatesFrom: 3,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,13)},
    {nr:  9, originatesFrom: 1,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,13)},
    {nr: 10, originatesFrom: 3,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,10)},
    {nr: 11, originatesFrom: 3,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,18)}
]
```

and I need to massage it into something like this:

```
List[
    {nr:  5, originatesFrom: 2,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,1)},
    {nr:  2, originatesFrom: null, lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,3)},
    {nr:  9, originatesFrom: 1,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,13)},
    {nr:  6, originatesFrom: 1     lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,7)},
    {nr:  7, originatesFrom: 1,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,4)},
    {nr:  4, originatesFrom: 1,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,1)},
    {nr:  1, originatesFrom: null, lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,3)},
    {nr: 11, originatesFrom: 3,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,18)},
    {nr:  8, originatesFrom: 3,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,13)},
    {nr: 10, originatesFrom: 3,    lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,10)},
    {nr:  3, originatesFrom: null, lastChanged: DateTime(2018,5,3)}
]
```

The complex sorting rules are as follows: Grouped by originatesFrom, within each group sorted by lastChanged descenting, and the groups sorted by (first instance's) lastChanged ascending. Finally the ones with null in originatesFrom should be stuffed in the bottom of each group matching their nr in originatesFrom. (yeah - it won't be something that comes out of the box here :-/ )

I have tried to start off by grouping them by originatesFrom, but I really need them to be split appart so I can sort them individually (I think?), and I am not sure it is wise to use linq at all, instead of going through all objects one at a time, building up several lists and ending up concatenating them in the end?

The good part is that there will seldomly be really many objects (so efficiency might not be that big of an issue). I won't know ahead of sorting how many groups there will be, and how many objects there will be in each group.

If I need to explain the sorting rules better, please let me know!

Comment: Why does originatesFrom = 1 come after originatesFrom = 2 and before originatesFrom = 3 ?

Comment: @sgmoore: Because of the `lastChanged` of the first item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is actually in a `List<T>` or similar (rather than via an `IQueryable<T>` where we might need to worry about whether the query can be translated), I believe this should work:

- Group by "`originatesFrom` if non-null; `nr` otherwise"
- Convert each group into a list, ordered on `originatesFrom` (descending) then by `lastChanged` (descending) - this will keep null `originatesFrom` at the end
- Order the list by "`lastChanged` of first item" (ascending)
- Flatten with `SelectMany`

Here's a complete example with your sample input data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var items = new[]
        {
             new { Number = 1, OriginatesFrom = (int?) null, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,3) },
             new { Number = 2, OriginatesFrom = (int?) null, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,3) },
             new { Number = 3, OriginatesFrom = (int?) null, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,3) },
             new { Number = 4, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 1, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,1) },
             new { Number = 5, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 2, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,1) },
             new { Number = 6, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 1, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,7) },
             new { Number = 7, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 1, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,4) },
             new { Number = 8, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 3, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,13) },
             new { Number = 9, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 1, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,13) },
             new { Number = 10, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 3, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,10) },
             new { Number = 11, OriginatesFrom = (int?) 3, LastChanged = new DateTime(2018,5,18 )}
        };

        var query = items
            .GroupBy(x => x.OriginatesFrom ?? x.Number)
            .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.OriginatesFrom)
                          .ThenByDescending(x => x.LastChanged)
                          .ToList())
            .OrderBy(g => g.First().LastChanged)
            .SelectMany(g => g)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }        
    }
}
```

Output, which matches your required order:

```
{ Number = 5, OriginatesFrom = 2, LastChanged = 01/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 2, OriginatesFrom = , LastChanged = 03/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 9, OriginatesFrom = 1, LastChanged = 13/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 6, OriginatesFrom = 1, LastChanged = 07/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 7, OriginatesFrom = 1, LastChanged = 04/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 4, OriginatesFrom = 1, LastChanged = 01/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 1, OriginatesFrom = , LastChanged = 03/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 11, OriginatesFrom = 3, LastChanged = 18/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 8, OriginatesFrom = 3, LastChanged = 13/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 10, OriginatesFrom = 3, LastChanged = 10/05/2018 00:00:00 }
{ Number = 3, OriginatesFrom = , LastChanged = 03/05/2018 00:00:00 }
```

Isn't LINQ wonderful?

Comment: Oh my godness - it looks so easy!! <3 ... I do hope this is working, but have to try it out first (and unfortunately I cannot try it out right now). But if this works out, I really need to learn how to linq! :-D Thanks a gazillion @daisy-shipton

Comment: @hasse: Like many of the most powerful tools, it's easy to use but takes a while to learn. This is only one approach, of course - but it was the simplest I could think of to start with.

Comment: @DaisyShipton can you explain to me what `.GroupBy(x => x.OriginatesFrom ?? x.Number)` means pls ?

Comment: @ThierryV: It says that the grouping key for an item is `x.OriginatesFrom` if it's non-null, or `x.Number` otherwise. The `??` operator is the null-coalescing operator - it basically results in the left operand if that's non-null, otherwise the right operand.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I understand what is ?? operator. But I wonder how c# choose the value for the GroupBy between OriginatesFrom  and Number

Comment: @ThierryV: If you understand the `??` operator, I'm not sure what else there is to explain. What do you mean by "choose the value" that isn't explained by how the `??` works?

Comment: @daisy-shipton: I can't get to test it on real data right now, but it sure does look like it does the trick on my test dataset! :-)
I am completely dazzled at how few steps it takes, and how relatively human readable it is! I almost think that your code is more readable than my feble attempt at explaining the sorting rules! :-D